# Why do not @JsonTypeInfo work together with @JsonIdentityInfo?

Tags: jackson

@JsonIdentityInfo works as expected with the following classes:

Baseclass:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator =  ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "uuid")
public class TestEntityBas {
    @JsonProperty
    public String uuid = "0001";
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class TestEntityGoa extends TestEntityBas  {
    @JsonProperty
    public String texten = "This is text!";
}
```

Container class:

```
public class TestEntity {
    @JsonProperty
    String stringer = "Hej hopp!";

    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    public TestEntityGoa goa = new TestEntityGoa(); 
}
```

The result is as expected:

```
{"stringer":"Hej hopp!","goa":"0001"}
```

When I add @JsonTypeInfo to the base class like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator =  ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "uuid")
public class TestEntityBas {
    @JsonProperty
    public String uuid = "0001";
}
```

Now the entire TestEntityGoa get serialized like this:

```
{"stringer":"Hej hopp!","goa":{"@class":"com.fodolist.model.TestEntityGoa","uuid":"0001","texten":"This is text!"}}
```

I expect the first result even when I use @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonIdentityInfo in the same class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A bug is filed at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything obviously wrong here, so you may have found a bug. Combination of type and identity info is bit tricky to handle so there may be edge cases that do not yet work as intended, so could you file a bug at Github issue tracker for this?